# How to multiply and divide two int values only using + and - operators

Tags: c++

How do I multiply and divide two int values without using the built in * and / operands.
Is it possible to use the + and - operands to achieve this?

```
int n1;
int n2;
int product;

cout << "Input 2 numbers you wish to multiply" << endl;
cin >> n1;
cin >> n2;

//perform multiplication operation here

return 0;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Of course it is! Multiply is (can be viewed as) simply repeated addition and similarly division is repeated subtraction. At least for integers...

Comment: This is more of a mathematics/logic question than a C++ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose that values of the numbers are positive. You can use loops. For example

```
int n1;
int n2;
int product;

cout << "Input 2 numbers you wish to multiply" << endl;
cin >> n1;
cin >> n2;

//perform multiplication operation here

product = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < n2; i++ ) product = product + n1; // or product += n1;

return 0;
```

Or you can use a recursive function. For example (the function works for positive and negative numbers)

```
int GetProduct( int n1, n2 )
{
  return n2 == 0 ? 0 : n1 + GetProduct( n1, n2 < 0 ? n2 + 1 : n2 - 1 );
}

product = GetProduct( n1, n2 );
```

Answer (score 5):

More std:

```
std::multiplies<int> x;
product = x.operator()(n1,n2);
```

There's also `std::divides`.

I posted this because you definitely can't use it in the assignment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Once again a for loop

```
int total = 0;
for (int loop = 0; loop < n1; ++loop) total += n2;
```

What happened to your primary school mathematics?

If you want negatives as well

```
int loop;
if (n1 < 0) for (loop = n1; loop > 0; loop++) total += n2;
else for (loop = 0; loop < n1; ++loop) total += n2;
```

Comment: I do not hold out much hope for the rest of the course

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Typo on my part. Anyway it is a daft question.

Answer (score 0):

If one of operands is power of two then you can use bit shift operator.

```
x << 1;
```

will multiply by 2,

```
x << 2;
```

will multply by 4 etc.

Comment: -1 That definitely doesn't answer the OP's question!

Comment: why not? Question:
 

How do I multiply and divide two int values without using the built in * and / operands? It's answer. Just assume that one of operands is power of two.

Comment: Blessed are those, who are able to read: _'Is it possible to use the + and - operands to achieve this?'_

Comment: It's just another way. Maybe it isn't exactly what he needs, but this might be helpful for another searching for: (C++) Multiply and Divide two int values WITHOUT using * or /.

Comment: I clarified the title.

Comment: Okay, I don't want to argue, I just thinked that it might be useful.

Comment: A more efficient algorithm uses shifts and adds for multiplication.  So you are on the right track.